# AS NewCompoundField - Concatenating values which may be NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following T-SQL query;

```
SELECT      
    Site.Address1 + CHAR(13) + Site.Address2 + CHAR(13) + 
        Site.Address3 + CHAR(13)  + Site.Town + CHAR(13) + 
        Site.eCounty AS SiteAddress
FROM Site
```

If any of the `Site.AddressX` fields making up `SiteAddress` are `NULL`, then `SiteAddress` is itself `NULL`. I would like a `Site.AddressX` field and it's following new line character to be ignored if it is `NULL`.

I have tried adding a `CASE` statement for a single field and it's new line character, but have not been able to get it to work.

```
SELECT      
    (CASE WHEN (Site.Address1 IS NULL) THEN '' ELSE Site.Address1 + CHAR(10)) +
        Site.Address2 + CHAR(13) + 
        Site.Address3 + CHAR(13)  + Site.Town + CHAR(13) + 
        Site.eCounty AS SiteAddress
FROM Site
```

How might I go about doing this?

Comment: COALESCE(Site.Address1 + CHAR(13), '') + and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT      
        COALESCE([Site].Address1 + CHAR(13), '')  + 
        COALESCE([Site].Address2 + CHAR(13), '')  + 
        COALESCE([Site].Address3 + CHAR(13), '')  + 
        COALESCE([Site].Town + CHAR(13), '') + 
        [Site].eCounty AS SiteAddress
FROM [Site]
```

Comment: I actually starting writing a very similar solution using `ISNULL()` but after a quick read about `COALESCE()` I converted over to using that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT      
    CASE WHEN Site.Address1 IS NULL THEN '' 
    ELSE Site.Address1 + CHAR(10) +
        Site.Address2 + CHAR(13) + 
        Site.Address3 + CHAR(13)  + Site.Town + CHAR(13) + 
        Site.eCounty END AS SiteAddress 
FROM SITE Site
```